# PHP, select a string between two strings, then get one value from the selected string

Tags: php

I have a file, with many parts of code.
Each part starts with `<form>` and ends with `</form>`.
Between each form, there is something like this: `<input type='text' name='date' value='2010-01-01'><input type='text' name='username' value='test'>`

I want to parse each part of the code with php and get the value of input username, where the value for input date is '2010-01-01'

Any solutions please?

example:

```
<form>
<input type='text' name='date' value='2010-01-01'>
<input type='text' name='username' value='test'> <!-- How can I get this value ('test')? -->
</form>
<form>
<input type='text' name='date' value='2010-01-02'>
<input type='text' name='username' value='test2'>
</form>
.
.
.
```

Comment: start with what? end with what?

Comment: @dqlopez start with `<form>` and end with `<form>`. Ataomega forgot the ``` and I can't edit because there is a pending edit which needs to be approved first...

Comment: Kind of multiple forms? Are you trying to submit each form contents on one submit button? If so, which form has that submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/form.*name=\'date\' value=\'2010-01-01\'.*name=\'username\' value=\'(.*)\'/Usim', $f, $r);
printf($r[1]);
```

Comment: thanks for all helps. let me try.

could someone please explain this? 

preg_match('/form.*name=\'date\' value=\'2010-01-01\'.*name=\'username\' value=\'(.*)\'/Usim', $f, $r);
printf($r[1]);

Comment: Regular expression are not an easy lesson, PHP regex documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php